# Retrieving computers where specified user is in local admin group?

Tags: windows, search, powershell, vbscript, active-directory

I have windows domain network, i have about 3000 hosts in there. I would like to just check the info which of those hosts having specified technical user account in their local admin groups. I am not that great at power shell, though I know the base things.

I belive that I have to make a list of all hosts across several subnets I have and then run a script that will try to log on those hosts with looking account credentials.

What could be the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

There is a very detailed post on TechNet about [listing all computers in domain](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2010/02/04/inventorying-computers-with-ad-powershell.aspx).

And here's the WMI query part (PowerShell, $aComputerList is a list of computer names):

```
foreach ($sComputerName in $aComputerList) {
  $sUserPattern = 'Win32_UserAccount.Domain="domainname",Name="username"'
  $sGroupPattern = 'Win32_Group.Domain="{0}",Name="Administrators"' -f $sComputerName

  $oResult = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $sComputerName -Class Win32_GroupUser | `
    Where-Object {
      ($_.groupcomponent -match $sGroupPattern) -and `
      ($_.partcomponent -match $sUserPattern) 
    }

  [Bool]$oResult
}
```

The hard part is that some computers probably won't be reachable (if they're turned off for instance). So you'll need to run your script several times and remove computers from the list as you get responses from them.

Comment: I've managed to get list of all domain computers. How exactly will I run that script now? Also, can I run it from not domain admin account, i.e. set credentials of account i am looking for, I assume I should get access denied reply else success data meaning that account have local admin rights on workstation.